# Cover a square with side $2^n$ with one unit square removed by three-square pieces

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

> Consider a square with side $2^n$ where $1$ unit square is removed from any position within the square. Prove that it is always possible to construct the shape using this building block:

[image: building block]

So far, I proved that the number of squares is a multiple of 3 and then I got lost.

Comment: It is a super-classical problem. Hint: induction on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea is to do induction over $n$. If you draw a picture along with the below explanation, you should get the idea.

Case $n=2$: We have a $2 \times 2$ square, no matter what square is removed you are always left with an L-tile.

Assume the proposition is true for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then consider a $2^{k+1} \times 2^{k+1}$ square with one tile removed. Split up the big board into four $2^k \times 2^k$ boards by drawing a horizontal and vertical line down the middle. Exactly one of the fields is a $2^k \times 2^k$ field with a tile removed; by inductive hypothesis it can be tiled. Place a L-tile in the middle of the $2^{k+1} \times 2^{k+1}$ board so that it covers the other three (complete) $2^k \times 2^k$ smaller boars. What is left are three $2^k \times 2^k$ boards, each with a tile removed, so they can also be tiled. Thus the $2^{k+1} \times 2^{k+1}$ board can be tiled.